# QGIS label conflict

Tags: qgis, labeling

**Background:**

Using 3.22.4, I am puzzled with labels in the main map window. When zoomed out to a scale where the labels will conflict with each other, QGIS adds unwanted red labels for those that should be omitted.

As an example, I have 11 closely-placed points labelled SWAKANE_01 through SWAKANE_11.  When zoomed out, all 11 labels are printed, and the conflict occurs.  When zoomed in, the conflict disappears.

Here's a screenshot zoomed out to 1:500,000 scale.  Note the conflicting red labels:
[image]

However, when I zoom in to a scale that allows all labels to differentiate, the red labels disappear, and all is as it should be.

Here's a screenshot zoomed in to 1:100,000 scale:
[image]

I can also make the red labels disappear by shrinking the font size, which makes me assume that this is a label placement conflict, but I am unable to stop it.  I have played around with all of the placement and obstacle settings in Layer Styling to no avail.

**Question:**

How to disable the red labels when conflicts occur?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to disable the red label when conflicts happen? Or how to avoid label conflicts and make them nicely appear at zoom-out level?  Which one?

Comment: Good point!  OP edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just press the red icon in the labeling toolbar:

[image]

The conflicted labels will disappear.

[image]